# How do I change the Localizable string file of the app programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an app that works with two languages arabic and english.
I made to Localizable string files one for each , and it is working properly, when I change the system language the language of the app is changing, but I need to do that when the user presses a button to change the application language while still inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var localized: String {
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        var lang = "en"

        if(appDelegate.isGreek)
        {
            lang = "el"
        }
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(lang, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)

        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
```

Where el is for greek language and this is extension to String class.