# How to pod Localized interface files(XIB, Storyboard) as xcode project structure and make internationalization work?

Tags: ios, storyboard, localizable.strings, podspec

As the [changes](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4635) of cocoapods 1.0.0.beta.1 say "Localized interface files (XIB, Storyboard) using Base Internationalization - Base.lproj/Main.xib and en.lproj/Main.strings are represented as a variant group named Main.xib" and as far as cocoapods 1.0.0.beta.1 "Special case interface files to use the XIB or Storyboard name for the variant group when using Base Internationalization."

I refer to the [demo](https://github.com/dlinsin/cocoapods-storyboard-sample) and use resource_bundles to organize my resources on my podspecs.

```
s.resource_bundles = {
     'Resources' => ['LocalizationDemo/LocalizationDemo/Resources/**/*.{lproj,storyboard}']
}
```

and my cocoapods version is 1.0.1 but the directories result is

```
-Resources
--en.lproj
---LocalizationDemo.strings
--LocalizationDemo.storyboard
--de.lproj
---LocalizationDemo.strings
```

It's not the result directories which I expected and the interface internationalization don't work.
Cloud anyone show me a correct usage or demo？

ADD: I use import/export localization by xcode before be pod to other projects. and I want it's could work by imported xliff files directly instead of add the IBOutlet or a subclass for UI controls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716367/how-do-i-change-the-localizable-string-file-of-the-app-programatically-in-swift/38716404#38716404

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora. Thank you for reply,but It's not help to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should write classes for your `controls` used in `XIB OR Storyboard` `Views` & assign the classes to respective control types like this -

```
class LocalizedTextField: UITextField {

    override func drawPlaceholderInRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let localizedPlaceHolder = self.placeholder!.localized
        self.placeholder = localizedPlaceHolder
        super.drawPlaceholderInRect(rect)
    }
}
class LocalizedLabel : UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let text = text {
            self.text = text.localized
            self.bounds.size.width = CGFloat.max
            self.sizeToFit()
        }
    }
}

class LocalizedButton : UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        for state in [UIControlState.Normal, UIControlState.Highlighted, UIControlState.Selected, UIControlState.Disabled, UIControlState.Focused] {
            if let title = titleForState(state) {
                setTitle(title.localized, forState: state)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String {

    var localized: String {
        let localizedValue =  NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
        if localizedValue == "" {

            return self
        }
        else
        {
            return localizedValue
        }
        return self

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I use import/export localization by xcode before be pod to other projects. and I want it's could work by imported xliff file directly instead of add the IBOutlet or a subclass for UI controls.